# How to change List parenthesis from [] to none

Tags: python, list, parentheses

short Question in Code:

```
i=0
k_start[i]
[8515]
i=1
k_start[i]
139253
```

How can i avoid the parenthesis in this example? Or Why at least do they appear with when i is 0?

Edit: Sorry for this bad Question, the problem was that i had a list of lists.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: If I had to guess, you have a list of lists. But without seeing the printout of k_start, it's impossible to tell

Comment: Also, please add some distinguishing mark to the commands to differentiate them from the output. >>> is a common choice

Comment: if `k_start = [[8515], 139253]` then, because it's list of lists

Comment: Your question makes no sense unless you show us what `k_start` is. Please show us by executing `k_start` at the prompt or by executing `print(k_start)` in just about any way, and showing us the output. Without that, your question will most probably be closed for being unclear.

Comment: Thank u guys, and yes it was just a list of lists what confused me as i was new to coding in general. So thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your first element is coming out as a sub-list but you can get rid of the brackets (in this one specific case) by calling k_start[0][0]...  Try printing k_start to see what the whole array looks like.  That way you can see what is happening and perhaps find a more general solution.  It's hard to do from the outside without more info, such as upstream code or a printout of the array.